# using AsyncTask for multiple actions

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am working in android.

**I have a ParseURL class in my MainActivity.java that extends AsyncTask:**

the class parses a URL and then does some work with it.

```
private class ParseURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        Document doc;
        try {
            Log.i("output", "trying to connect..");
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://sirim.co.il/").get();
            Log.i("output", "connected");
            Elements metaElems = doc.select("a[class=mainlevelmatkonim]");
            for (Element metaElem : metaElems) {
                String c = metaElem.text();
                buffer.append(c + "\r\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        httpInfo.setText(s);
    }
}
```

my question is - 
if I want to use again a AsyncTask to parse another page - but do different actions with the parsed page -

**should I use the same class or create a new one?**

what is the right way? have a "if" statement or something like that to check what to do with the parsed page? or have a few AsyncTask classes that do different work?

thnaks in advance,
Ofek

Comment: That depends. What would be examples of the different actions? If it's something that you can simply pass different `params` then just use the same class.

Comment: [take a look](http://nobalg.tumblr.com/post/98543748225/android-asynctasks-one-after-the-other)

Comment: @codeMagic thnaks for your answers. lets say that first job is to populate a list with some data from the URL. the second job is to go over the list and extract some data from different URL based on user's combobox choise. (Two pretty different jobs). do you think its okay to have two AsyncTask classes ? or have one that will do both jobs based on some parameter

Comment: Two are fine but, depending on how much time it will take to extract the data from the list, you may be able to do that on the UI thread and not need a second task.

Comment: okay thanks! one more thing, sould I put the AsyncTask classes in the MainActivity and have them be private? or in the src folder and have them be public? and why? thanks!

Comment: If it's only going to be used by that activity then make it an inner class because no one else will need it. If another activity will use it, put it in it's own file.

Answer (score 1):

Use a parameter for your task :

```
private class ParseURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        Document doc;
        try {
            Log.i("output", "trying to connect..");
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url[0]).get();
            Log.i("output", "connected");
            Elements metaElems = doc.select("a[class=mainlevelmatkonim]");
            for (Element metaElem : metaElems) {
                String c = metaElem.text();
                buffer.append(c + "\r\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        httpInfo.setText(s);
    }
}
```

Use it like this :

```
ParseURL task = new ParseURL();
task.execute("http://sirim.co.il/");
```

But you would have to recreate the task [everytime you have to use it again](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

*The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)*

You could create a helper in `ParseURL`

```
private class ParseURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    public static void parse(String url)
    {
        ParseURL task = new ParseURL();
        task.execute(url);
        return task;
    }

    // [...]
```

And use it like this :

```
ParseURL task = ParseURL.parse("http://sirim.co.il/");
```

**About the different action**

You could adapt your OnPostExecute method, and you use an enum to switch between action

```
private class ParseURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    public enum ParseURLAction {ACTION1, ACTION2, ACTION3};

    public static void parse(String url, ParseURLAction action)
    {
        ParseURL task = new ParseURL(action);
        task.execute(url);
        return task;
    }

    private ParseURLAction action;

    public ParseURL(ParseURLAction action)
    {
        this.action = action;
    }

    // [...]

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
       super.onPostExecute(s);
       switch (action)
       {
           case ACTION1:
                // TODO something
                break;

           // [...]     
   }
```

Usage :

```
ParseURL task = ParseURL.parse("http://sirim.co.il/", ParseURL.ParseURLAction.ACTION1);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. does is make a difference if I use two different classes? or have just one that could do both actions? what I mean is if one is better than the other and why. and one more issue - should I put the classes in the MainAcitivity and have them be private, or in the src folder like the rest of the classes and have them be public ?

Comment: It's all about code duplication. It your 2 classes are going to share more than a relevant amount of code, it would be good to make one class with internal switching logic

Answer (score 0):

Pass another parameter to doinbackground function about which indicates your url.Based on that parameter write your actions.

Comment: you mean pass a parameter that indicates what to do in the method? and than have a switch-case for example, doing actions depending on that parameter

Answer (score 0):

**In execute command you can of asyc task you can pass as many paramters as you can.**

```
ParseURL task = new ParseURL();
task.execute(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3);   

@Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
   if(strings[0]== your condition){
       // do this
   }
   if(strings[1]== your condition){
       // do this
   }
    if(strings[2]== your condition){
       // do this
   }
 }
```

Comment: @DanielHussain thnaks for your answer. lets say that first job is to populate a list with some data from the URL. the second job is to go over the list and extract some data from different URL based on user's combobox choise. (Two pretty different jobs). do you think its okay to have two AsyncTask classes ? or have one that will do both jobs based on some parameter

Comment: In my opinion create two task. if my answer helps you then vote up and tick the answer. thanks